# Group by Vertical and Horizontal Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

please consider table below (TableName: Registration)

| Type1 | Type2 | Type3 | Type4 | Registration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 2023-05-29 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2023-04-29 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 2023-05-29 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 2023-06-29 |

I'm looking for a query which groups the data by Type1, Type2, Type3, and Type4 and shows the sums of Amount having each one month  so that it returns:

| Month | Type1 | Type2 | Type3 | Type4 | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| April | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| May | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| June | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| July | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Here is my current SQL

```
SELECT 
            DATEPART(month, x.RegistrationDateTime) AS Closing_Month
          , COUNT (x.Type1) ,
           COUNT (x.Type2),
           COUNT (x.Type3),
           COUNT (x.Type4)
          
     FROM(
             SELECT 
                    
                   'Type1' = 
                  CASE                  
                    WHEN r.inp = 1
                    AND bp.BusinessPartnerID = 508
                    THEN 1 ELSE 0 
                  END
                  , 'Type2' =
                  CASE                  
                    WHEN r.inp = 0
                    AND bp.BusinessPartnerID = 508
                    THEN 1 ELSE 0 
                  END
                  ,'Type3' =
                  CASE                  
                    WHEN r.inp = 1
                    AND bp.BusinessPartnerID = 509
                    THEN 1 ELSE 0 
                  END
                  , 'Type4' =
                  CASE                  
                    WHEN r.inp = 0
                    AND bp.BusinessPartnerID = 509
                    THEN 1 ELSE 0 
                  END, Registration
                 
             FROM Registration AS r 
             INNER JOIN BusinessPartner bp ON r.id = bp.RegistrationID
                  
           
              
          ) AS x
          GROUP BY DATEPART(month, x.RegistrationDateTime),Type1,Type2,Type3,Type4;
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above query is product specific in several ways.)

Comment: I am using sql server dbms

Comment: Question is unclear, provide as much relevant information as possible in your question. Ex: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I've created an example with this code:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Registration
CREATE TABLE Registration (
    Type1 INT,
    Type2 INT,
    Type3 INT,
    Type4 INT,
    RegistrationDateTime DATE
);

INSERT INTO Registration (Type1, Type2, Type3, Type4, RegistrationDateTime)
VALUES 
    (0, 1, 0, 0, '2023-01-29'),
    (1, 0, 0, 0, '2023-01-30'),
    (0, 0, 1, 0, '2023-02-15'),
    (1, 0, 0, 0, '2023-02-25'),
    (0, 0, 0, 1, '2023-03-10'),
    (1, 0, 0, 0, '2023-03-12'),
    (0, 0, 0, 1, '2023-04-01'),
    (0, 0, 0, 1, '2023-04-05'),
    (0, 0, 1, 0, '2023-04-10'),
    (0, 1, 0, 0, '2023-05-02'),
    (1, 0, 0, 0, '2023-05-15'),
    (0, 0, 1, 0, '2023-06-01'),
    (1, 0, 0, 0, '2023-06-02'),
    (0, 0, 1, 0, '2023-07-20'),
    (1, 0, 0, 0, '2023-08-12'),
    (0, 1, 0, 0, '2023-08-18'),
    (0, 0, 1, 0, '2023-09-05'),
    (0, 0, 0, 1, '2023-09-30');
```

Trying to replicate what you've done. And with this query:

```
SELECT 
    FORMAT(x.RegistrationDateTime, 'MMMM') AS Month,
    SUM(Type1) AS Type1,
    SUM(Type2) AS Type2,
    SUM(Type3) AS Type3,
    SUM(Type4) AS Type4,
    COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM (
    SELECT 
        CASE 
            WHEN r.Type1 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 
        END AS Type1,
        CASE 
            WHEN r.Type2 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 
        END AS Type2,
        CASE 
            WHEN r.Type3 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 
        END AS Type3,
        CASE 
            WHEN r.Type4 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 
        END AS Type4,
        r.RegistrationDateTime
    FROM Registration AS r 
) AS x
GROUP BY FORMAT(x.RegistrationDateTime, 'MMMM')
ORDER BY MIN(x.RegistrationDateTime);
```

I've created your desired output as you can see here:

[image]

Comment: First, for each date never have double cell with value 1. Second, Type1 value of Month April is 2 while there is only one row that has value 1 for Type 1 in '2023-04-12'. Third, Total value in each month is wrong because it sum of Type1, Type2, Type3, Type4 value (Ex.: Total value for month January is 0).

Comment: Changed. I think I understand better your question.